# Не подключаются стили в теме wordpress с использованием wp_enqueue_style

Tags: php, wordpress

Пишу в `functions.php` код:

```
function add_theme_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_styles');
```

Стили не грузятся. В `header.php` есть `wp_head()`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что отладчик показывает? Есть там кусок кода '/css/main.css' или он какую-то ошибку в отладчике пишет?

Comment: Я проверил, метод работает. Проверьте путь и наличие самого файла. Так же wp_head().

Answer (score 2):

Я проверил, метод работает. Проверьте путь и наличие самого файла. Так же wp_head(). Если вы видите, что файл физически есть, но выдается 404, тогда измените постоянные ссылки на стандартные в wordpress на время разработки и верните обратно, после чего должно заработать. Это частая проблема при переносе и добавлении новых файлов.

Чтобы запустить механизм сканирования url нужно пройти сюда

http://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

[image: Меню управления ссылок в wordpress]

После чего поменять местами параметры и вернуть исходные, если необходимо.

[image: Для перезаписи правил отображения по url, верните на значения по умолчанию, а затем на те которые у вас стояли до этого]

После чего потерянные страницы и классы будут отображены по назначеному вами адресу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я новичок в этом вопросе, отладчика у меня нет... И можно пояснить, что значит - "измените постоянные ссылки на стандартные в wordpress" ? Извините за глупый вопрос.

Comment: Я дополнил вам ответ, код можно просмотреть на f12 при помощи консоли

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Comment: Закройте вопрос тогда, вам и мне карма тогда упадет